# How can I get font-size 0 to work in Android?

Tags: android, html, css, drupal

I have the following as part of my drupal form:

```
$form['update'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Update cart'),
  '#submit' => array('uc_cart_view_form_submit'),
  '#attributes'=> array('class' => 'update_cart'),
);
```

And the relevant css:

```
#edit-update.update_cart
{
  float : left;
  border:0 none;
  font-size:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#edit-update.update_cart {
  background: url('/themes/mytheme/images/cart_page/update-cart.png') no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
  float: left;
  height: 22px;
  width: 115px;
}
```

In Chrome, font-size 0 works and doesn't display the text. This is the behavior I want because there is other css that adds a background image:

[image: Update cart button]

However, on my Android tablet, you can see the text. What can I do to have the text not display? I cannot change the value in the form element because I need that value to test which submit button was pressed (There are 4 on the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using text-indent?

```
text-indent:-9999px;
```